# How can I change the default directory for gnome-terminal without editing .bashrc?

Tags: command-line, launcher, gnome-terminal, directory, bashrc

How do I set the default working directory of a gnome-terminal opened via `Ctrl-Alt-T` or via the Launcher or any other quick means to a gnome-terminal? Presently it defaults to `~`. I know about `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/dir` but that's not as quick as `Ctrl-Alt-T`.

Note that I can't put a `cd /path/to/dir` in `.bashrc` because I also need `nautilus-open-terminal` to continue to open at the directory Nautilus is displaying at the time.

Comment: Note that in 16.04 when I try to install nautilus-open-terminal I get `Package nautilus-open-terminal is not available`. It might be obsolete. From inside Nautilus right click 'open terminal' is doing the desired operation so that package does not seem necessary anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If editing .bashrc is not an option, there are various alternatives:

#### 1. Edit the `Exec=` line of your launcher:

- Copy the global `gnome-terminal.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications`

  ```
  cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
  ```
- Open the local copy with gedit:

  ```
  gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
  ```
- Look up the *first occurrence* of the `Exec=` line, change it into:

  ```
  Exec=gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/your/directory
  ```

  where the path needs to be a full path.
- ***Either Log out and back in, or run `source ~/.profile`***.

  Now when you click on the launcher or run `gnome-terminal` from Dash, it will open a terminal in your directory. The right-click option will work as usual. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> however will still take you to your home directory.

#### 2. Create a new shortcut

Add the command `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/your/directory` to a shortcut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/your/directory
```

Use full path here.

#### 3. Add a quicklist -item to your `gnome-terminal` launcher.

- Copy the global `.desktop` file locally and open the local copy, as in `[1.]`
- Look for the line:

  ```
  Actions=New;
  ```
- Change it into (in my example)

  ```
  Actions=New;Open terminal in Documenten;
  ```
- To the very end of the file, add a section:

  ```
  [Desktop Action Open terminal in Documenten]
  Name=Open terminal in Documenten
  Exec=gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/jacob/Documenten
  OnlyShowIn=Unity;
  ```

  [image]

#### 4. Change the functionality of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

If you'd insist on using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal, first disable the current shortcut, by running the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal ""
```

This will make the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> available as a *custom shortcut*. Then add the command

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/your/directory
```

to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Again: use a full path here.

Comment: I would have expected the last one was your favourite, since it uses Ctrl+Alt+T :)

Comment: I like the first suggestion. In the same file Actions=New is associated with another `exec` variable and the same --working-directory can be set there.